# Problem loading xlsx file with pandas in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I imported a new pandas version and now cannot import xlsx files as I used to. I have looked at similar issues and most seem to work when adding `engine=""openpyxl"`, however in my case when I run the following code:

```
df = pd.read_excel("IPO_10.xlsx", engine="openpyxl")
df.head()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
    344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
    346             return None
    347         else:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
    732         GH3541, GH3573
    733         """
--> 734         width, height = console.get_console_size()
    735         max_columns = get_option("display.max_columns")
    736         nb_columns = len(self.columns)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py in to_html(self, buf, encoding, classes, notebook, border)
    980             Buffer to write to. If None, the output is returned as a string.
    981         encoding : str, default “utf-8”
--> 982             Set character encoding.
    983         classes : str or list-like
    984             classes to include in the `class` attribute of the opening

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/html.py in __init__(self, formatter, classes, border, table_id, render_links)
     54         self.col_space = {
     55             column: f"{value}px" if isinstance(value, int) else value
---> 56             for column, value in self.fmt.col_space.items()
     57         }
     58 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute items
```

and my data frame is then printed as output. How can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: can you post the full stack?

Comment: @umar Added it, let me know if it helps